# "RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0" when trying to get a barcode

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter I actually write a smartphone app for my company. There is also a barcode reader to legitimize customers to enter the store.

The problem is that whenever I want to convert a 13 number string into a barcode I get the error shown above.

For first time using the App the customer types his number into a TextField. The number (originally a String) will be stored in a private variable _number (also from type String) for further processing.

Even if I use my function

```
convert2barcode('1111111111116')
```

the barcode is shown correctly, but not for

```
convert2barcode(_number)
```

I have no idea why. If I write

```
print(_number)
```

I get the correct result (e.g. '1111111111116').

Hope you can help. Tell me if you need more code information.

Best regards.

**EDIT**
I wrote a more simple example to understand what I mean.

I've a TextField where a numeric String will be converted into a barcode at submitting.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'barcode.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GUI(),
    );
  }
}

class GUI extends StatefulWidget {
  GUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GUI> createState() => _GUI();
}

class _GUI extends State<GUI> {
  bool _isVisible = false;
  String numer = "";

  void showWidget() {
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = !_isVisible;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext contet) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Visibility(
        child: Row(
          children: /*[
          Text(_numer.runtimeType.toString())
        ]*/
              Barcode.convert2Barcode(numer),
        ),
        visible: _isVisible,
        replacement: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                numer = value;
                showWidget();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code which caused the exception:

```
Barcode.convert2Barcode(numer),
```

If I run the code I'll get the error shown in the headline.
Only If I write

```
convert2barcode('1111111111116'),
```

the barcode will be shown correctly.

I have output the type of the variable with runtimeType for both ('1111111111116' and _numer). It's always the same (String). Even if I make something like this

```
_numer = '1111111111116';
print(_numer);
```

I will get the correct result.

I have really no idea what this exception cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `TextField`'s `onSubmit` is not called, the `number` is empty. That's the reason you get the error.

Replace

```
Barcode.convert2Barcode(numer),
```

with

```
if (number.isNotEmpty)
  Barcode.convert2Barcode(numer),
```